# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (I want to store the result in index)

Tags: python

```
for j in range(len(a)):
    for k in range(len(test_list)):
        if(a[j]==test_list[k]):
            index=list(map(int,k))
```

I want to store the result in index

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `k` is an integer, so why are you using `map` and `list`? Are you trying to create a list containing the indexes of the elements in `test_list` that are equal to any of the elements in `a`?

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect `index = list(map(int,k))`.

Comment: map() function returns a map object(which is an iterator) of the results after applying the given function to each item of a given iterable (list, tuple etc.)

Comment: Are you trying to build a list of all the indices for which `test_list` and `a` are the same?

Comment: @bart-khalid `int`, like all types, can be used as a function.  Consider `x = int("123")`.

Comment: "I want to store the result in index" -- what result?  If `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `test_list = [2, 4, 6, 8]` what should `index` be?

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to loop over two lists and find the indexes of the elements in `test_list` that are also in `a`, you can do:

```
indexes = []
for item in a:
    for index, other_item in enumerate(test_list):
        if item == other_item:
            indexes.append(index)
```

or simply use list comprehension:

```
[index for index, other_item in enumerate(test_list) for item in a if item == other_item]
```

I'm not sure if I'd recommend list comprehension with nested for-loops, though, since it hurts readability.

A cleaner list comprehension would be:

```
[index for index, item in enumerate(test_list) if item in a]
```